# INSERT if exists UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I've been looking at other resources and am just getting a bit confused. I'd like to relate an example to my problem.

I have a game server which stores a unique id from steam in a database, and along with this has a column for specific permissions to that user. E.g id: 712309123810 permission: default

What I want to achieve is sending data from a form; $Id and $permission are posted. Insert this data into the database under columns for example sake; 'Id' and 'permission'. I can do this, what I am having issues is understanding how to UPDATE only the $permission column if the $id already exists in the db.

I have read about ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE , but am confused about how to correctly utilize it. I am fairly new to mysql.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can an `id` have multiple permissions?

Comment: Just one permission is needed Gordon

Answer (score 0):

The `on duplicate key` fires when the insert part of the statement violates a unique constraint (in your case - the primary key on `id`). So, to put it all together:

```
INSERT INTO mytbale (id, permissions) 
VALUES (:id, :permissions)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE permissions = :permissions
```

Answer (score 0):

It's explained rather well by the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Your query might be something like:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, permissions) VALUES (712309123810, "default")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE permissions = "default";
```

This requires that the table contains a unique or primary key on the id column.

Normally, if you attempt to insert a new row that would create a duplicate value for a unique or primary key, it is an error. Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` changes that: instead, your insert transforms into an update.

The example query I gave will insert a new record if none with that id exists, or it will update the permissions of the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Typically, an `id` can have multiple permissions.  If so, you don't want to overwrite the permissions; you want to accumulate them.  If this is the case, you might need junction table to handle this:

```
create table UserPermissions (
    UserPermissionsId int auto_increment primary key,
    UserId int not null,
    PermissionId int not null,
    constraint fk_UserPermissions_UserId foreign key UserId references Users(UserId),
    constraints fk_UserPermissions_PermissionId foreign key Permissions references Permissions (PermissionId)
);
```

If a user has only one permission that gets overwritten, then `on duplicate key update` is appropriate.